# How extract a picture from a dll file with MEF

Tags: c#, image, dll, mef, jpeg

I would like to get back a "jpg" file from a "dll", that I load with MEF. 
How can I succeed it? 
Thanks

Comment: this might help you: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/277865-retrieving-embedded-image-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply export?

```
class MyImageExportDllClass
{
   [Export("MyExternalImage)]
   public Image MyImage {get; privtae set;}

   public MyImageExportDllClass()
   {
      this.MyImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");
   }

}
```

other project

```
var image = compositioncontainer.GetExport<Image>("MyExternalImage");
```

ps: code is handwritten, so some errors maybe